# Assigning to an array sorted secondary diagonal C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I keep getting this error: "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" while trying to reassign elements of my array which are on the secondary diagonal

```
if ((i + j) == (rows - 1))
            {
                arr[i][j] = secDiag[i];
            }
```

Full method to print initial array, secondary diagonal, sorted diagonal and then array with this sorted diagonal:

```
void print(const int** arr, int rows, int columns) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }   
    
    cout << endl << "Secondary Diagonal: ";
    int* secDiag = new int[rows];
    int r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        c = columns - r - 1;
        if (c < 0) break;
        secDiag[r] = arr[r][c];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) cout << setw(7) << secDiag[i];
    cout << endl;

    cout << "After sorted: ";
    sort(secDiag, secDiag + r); 
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        cout << setw(7) << secDiag[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if ((i + j) == (rows - 1))
            {
                arr[i][j] = secDiag[i];
            }
        cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    delete[] secDiag;
}
```

Full code (I needed to give user a choice how to create an array: with `malloc` `calloc` or `new`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int** createMalloc(int, int);
int** createCalloc(int rows, int columns);

int** createNew(int rows, int columns);
void deleteNew(int** arr, int rows);

void init(int**, int, int);
void freeMemory(int**, int);
void print(const int**, const int, const int);

void initPrint(int** arr, int rows, int columns);

void main() {
    int rowCount, colCount;
    cout << "Enter number of rows: "; cin >> rowCount;
    cout << "Enter number of columns: "; cin >> colCount;
    cout << " Array creation algorithm\n";
        start:
    cout << "Input number : \n1 for malloc\n2 for calloc\n3 for new\n";
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    switch (k) {
        case 1: {
            int** a = createMalloc(rowCount, colCount);
            initPrint(a, rowCount, colCount);

            freeMemory(a, rowCount);
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            int** a = createCalloc(rowCount, colCount);
            initPrint(a, rowCount, colCount);

            freeMemory(a, rowCount);
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            int** a = createNew(rowCount, colCount);
            initPrint(a, rowCount, colCount);

            deleteNew(a, rowCount);
            break;
        }
        default: cout << endl << "Input 1, 2 or 3, please.";
            cout << endl << endl;
            goto start;
    }
}

int** createMalloc(int rows, int columns) {
    int** arr = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(columns * sizeof(int));
    }
    return arr;
}

int** createCalloc(int rows, int columns) {
    int** arr = (int**)calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)calloc(columns, sizeof(int));
    }
    return arr;
}

int** createNew(int rows, int columns) {
    int** arr = new int* [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[columns];
    }
    return arr;
}

void initPrint(int** arr, int rows, int columns) {
    init(arr, rows, columns);
    print((const int**)arr, rows, columns);
    //printSecondaryDiagonal(arr, rows, columns);
}

void init(int** arr, int rows, int columns) {
    const int Low = -21, High = 34;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = Low + rand() % (High - Low + 1);
        }
    }
}

void freeMemory(int** arr, int rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}

void deleteNew(int** arr, int rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
}

void print(const int** arr, int rows, int columns) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }   
    
    cout << endl << "Secondary Diagonal: ";
    int* secDiag = new int[rows];
    int r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        c = columns - r - 1;
        if (c < 0) break;
        secDiag[r] = arr[r][c];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) cout << setw(7) << secDiag[i];
    cout << endl;

    cout << "After sorted: ";
    sort(secDiag, secDiag + r); 
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        cout << setw(7) << secDiag[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if ((i + j) == (rows - 1))
            {
                arr[i][j] = secDiag[i];
            }
        cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    delete[] secDiag;
}
```

P.S. Two-dimensional array in the beginning (and then with sorted diagonal) must be necessarily a dynamic one. Also, cannot do it using `vector`. Only `malloc`, `calloc` and `new`

Comment: What do you think that `const` means here `const int** arr`? If you want to modify your array, don't declare it `const`.

Comment: and why when I assign `arr [i][j]` in the function `init` as let`s say 5, it works fine and print an array with only 5s in it?

Comment: Because in your `init` function the array is not declared `const`.

Comment: `void init(int** arr, int rows, int columns) {` and `void print(const int** arr, int rows, int columns) {` Only `print` has `const`.